# why the text in Arabic in a jlabel (the jlabel is in jpanel) does not appear in pdf with jPanel.print (Graphics2D)?

Tags: java, itext, jpanel, jlabel, arabic

why the text in Arabic in a jlabel (the jlabel is in jpanel) does not appear in pdf with jPanel.print (Graphics2D)? the French text is displayed well! see the images for more information, thank you:

```
public class PaneltopdfView extends FrameView {

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        jTextField1.setBackground( jPanel1.getBackground());
        // print the panel to pdf
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
            PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(500, 500);
            Graphics2D g2 = template.createGraphics(500, 500);
            jPanel1.print(g2);
            g2.dispose();
            contentByte.addTemplate(template, 30, 300);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document.isOpen()) {
                document.close();
            } // TODO add your handling code here:
        }
        File file = new File("test.pdf");
        if (file.exists()) {
            try {
                desktop.open(file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Logger.getLogger(CalculerAbsIndiv.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: application]
[image: file pdf]

Comment: Was the font unicode?

Comment: what happens if you use `paint` instead of `print`?

Comment: it did not work: same result!:jLabel1.setFont(new Font("SimSun",Font.PLAIN, 12));

Comment: paint: 
 
it did not work: same result!

Answer (score 3):

The issue is probably a font/encoding problem.

- First, not every font has every possible character. If you select a font (e.g. Helvetica) and ask it to produce Arabic text, it won't work.

  The character being displayed (the actual pixel information) is called a glyph. The code (ASCII, unicode) that we associate with a character is
  called a codepoint.

  Whenever iText encounters a codepoint for which
  no glyph information is available in the selected font, it will
  simply skip that character. If you are using the wrong font, you will
  never see any characters.
- Second, if you are using Arabic, consider using iText7 and pdfCalligraph. Arabic (as well as several other languages) have what is known as opentype features. Or, to put it simply, they require more than the simple 'look up glyph, place glyph here'. Arabic for instance has complex rules that govern glyph order, and ligatures.

  pdfCalligraph knows all these rules for various scripts, and applies them without any effort from your side.

Comment: Please be aware that `PdfGraphics2D` is no longer available in iText 7.

Comment: please an example with iText 7 (panel to pdf)?

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/font-examples/clone-language-specific-examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, I could solve this problem by transforming my jpanel into an image:

```
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(jPanel1.getWidth(),jPanel1.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
    jPanel1.paint(g2);
    try{
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("test.jpg"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
```

}